# jQuery Script interfering with Navigation Links

Tags: jquery, html, django, heroku, jquery-cycle

I just deployed a Django app on Heroku here - http://enigmatic-castle-9385.herokuapp.com/

I'm having issues with the permanent links at the top of the page. When I navigate to any page from home, the navigation links become unresponsive. Seems to happen 50% of the time. In Firefox, the navigation completely disappears on certain pages. I am pretty sure this is due to the jQuery script because, when disabled, the links work as normal. I don't see any of these issues on local though, just on the deployed site.

I have a Base HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'logo.png' %}" type="image/png">
    <title>Hannah Young Photography</title>
</head>
<body>  
<div>
    <a href="/"><img class = "logo" src = "{% static 'logo.png' %}"/></a>
    <p class = "topnav-white-header">
        Hannah Harley Young is a party & event photographer based in London. She shoots mainly high profile events, but also commissioned for private parties as well as portrait
    </p>            
    <ul class = "navigation-bar">
        <li><a href="/contact" class = "nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="/clients" class = "nav-link">CLIENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/personal" class = "nav-link">PERSONAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="/fashion" class = "nav-link">FASHION</a></li>
        <li><a href="/portrait" class = "nav-link">PORTRAITS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/party" class = "nav-link">PARTIES</a></li>
    </ul>   
<div>       
{% block image %}
{% endblock %}
</div>      
</body> 
</html>
```

The gallery pages (parties, portrait, fashion, personal links all have the same structure) look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body>
{% block image %}   

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'jquery.cycle.all.js' %}"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slideshow")
        .cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        next: '.right-arrow',
        prev: '.left-arrow',
        timeout: 0,
        pager: '.slide-nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function paginate(idx, el) {
                    return '<a class="bullet" href="#" >&bull;</a>'

        }
    })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".left-arrow").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","{% static 'left-arrow-blue.png' %}");
        }, function() {
            $(this).attr("src","{% static 'left-arrow.png' %}");
        });
        }); 

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".right-arrow").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","{% static 'right-arrow-blue.png' %}");
        }, function() {
            $(this).attr("src","{% static 'right-arrow.png' %}");
    });
    });

</script>

<img class = "right-arrow" src = "{% static 'right-arrow.png' %}">
<img class = "left-arrow" src = "{% static 'left-arrow.png' %}">

<div class = "slideshow">
    {% for photo in gallery %}
    <div class = "slide">
        <img class = "gallery-image" src ="{{ photo.image.url }}"/>
        <div class = "caption-container">
            {% for client in photo.client.all %}
            <div class = "client">client: {{ client.name }}
                <div class = "slide-nav"></div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}    
            <span class = "caption">{{ photo.caption }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}    
</div>  

{% endblock %} 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updates my answer, I think I found your problem.

Comment: @Sebsemillia Thanks, I'm looking into it now, I'll update you in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your problem.

It is your css, on some pages the elements generated/used by your jquery scripts overlay the navigation, therefore you can't click, or sometimes see them.

You have to clean up your css, best if you read about [z-index](http://www.csstutorial.net/2010/06/using-the-css-z-index/) , that should help you solve your problem. (use firebug or chrome dev tools!)

Here are some more hints on your jQuery usage:

Combine all the scripts in your `$(document).ready(function(){ })` functions into 1 document.ready function.

For the functionality in these scripts, you don't even need the document.ready.

If possible, include these scripts at the bottom of the page for better performance, the document.ready just does load after the DOM is finished.

Comment: Thanks. You are right that there are elements covering the navigation bar but I'm confused as to why that's happening - the site works fine on local. I'm familiar with Z-Index. I've given the navigation bar an index of 10 but that hasn't helped. I will work on the other changes you mentioned but I don't think they will solve the issue.

Comment: the .slide inside your .slideshow div has the css position: relative, try setting it to absolute

Comment: Hey, I think I fixed the issue by adding a few <br> tags above my slideshow div. It's pushed the slides down below the navigation bar.

Comment: Glad you made it work, even if it not the most professional solution. But you should check your source code, there are some mistakes. On your Fashion page for example you have the body tag twice.. use http://validator.w3.org/ for markup error detection..